# ItemTouchHelper swipe only

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, swipe, itemtouchhelper

i have used a Recycler View, i just want to swipe a particular item using TouchHelper and goto another activity, but the problem is that, swiping occurs new activity also starts but on going back to same activity, card that i swiped is not there meaning it deletes/invisble the particular item.

i have not notified Adapter either.

```
ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {

                @Override
                public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) { return false; }

                @Override
                public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target, int direction) {
                    int targetPosition = target.getAdapterPosition();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_mainAll.this, test.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    //Toast.makeText(Activity_mainAll.this, ""+targetPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

EDIT: item data is not being removed from ArrayList, just physically card disappears, i just want Swiped Card to be there when i go back to Card Activity

Comment: myBad! notifying data adapter did the work. `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use onResume method to reload

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

or

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemChanged(targetPosition);
    // targetPosition cannot be null
}
```